# Generating Channel Select for Multichannel ADC

Tags: fpga, adc, verilog

I am using a FPGA to control a 4-channel ADC (ADC084S101) to sample four different analog voltages. In order to tell the ADC which channel to sample next, there is a control register that can be written with 00, 01, 10, or 11 to sample channels 0, 1, 2, or 3, respectively (See the table below).
[image: Control Register Bits]

I'm not sure if the approach that I'm taking with this module is correct. What my intention is that the module will take the same CS and SCLK signals that are going to the ADC and also a 2-bit number that corresponds to the next channel that is to be sampled. Then, upon each falling edge of CS, reset a counter to 0. On each rising edge of SCLK, clock out the appropriate bit of the stream using the incremented count as an index, either 0 if it's *don't care* or the 2 bits that correspond to the next channel if at the appropriate index.

```
module GenerateNextAddr(
input cs,
input sclk,
input [1:0] addr,
output reg dout
);

 reg [4:0] count;
 reg [1:0] currentAddr;

 always @(posedge sclk or negedge cs) begin
    if (cs) begin
        count <= 0;
        currentAddr <= addr;
    end else    begin
        count <= count + 1;
        if ((count != 4'b0011) && (count != 4'b0100)) begin //If we're clocking out any of the 'dont care' bits of the ADC
            dout <= 0;
        end else if (count == 4'b0011) begin
            dout <= currentAddr[1];
        end else if (count == 4'b0100) begin
            dout <= currentAddr[0];
        end
    end
 end 
endmodule
```

I am struggling to get the Verilog implemented for outputting this bitstream (I am a software developer that has only been working with Verilog for  a few months). The Verilog module that I have written above is not synthesizable and I'm not sure why (my development board is a Nexys 3 from Digilent). The error message is, "Assignment under multiple single edges is not supported for synthesis."

Comment: Try changing your first if statement to `if (~cs) begin ...`. You're trying to make a low-active asyncronous reset (because of the negedge cs sensitivity) but then you actually do the reset action when `cs` is high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make logic with an asyncronous reset signal called `cs`.

But you mismatched the edge sensitivity for the reset signal.
You're watching for the falling edge of `cs`, but the logic calls for resetting when `cs` is high.

You need to either have sensitivity to `posedge cs` and reset the registers when `cs` is high, or have sensitivity to `negedge cs` (like you have) and reset the registers when `cs` is low.

For example,

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge cs) begin
    if(~cs) begin
         count <= 0
         ...
    end else begin
         ...
    end
 end
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. I thought that the `if(cs)` meant _if the block is currently being driven by the falling edge of cs_.

Comment: Nope, `cs` is just being used to refer to the logic level of the `cs` signal. For a syncronous reset, you wouldn't have even mentioned `cs` in the sensitivity list, just refer to it in the if block the same way you do `addr` and `currentAddr`.